# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli)

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services

I'm working on datastax cassandra java driver project using Maven. I've tried to build it successfully in local machine with maven and Eclipse.

However, when I deployed the project in Amazon AWS. Every time, I ran the `exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=”com.example.cassandra.App”`, which is a simple `Hello World` java file. However, I got an error:

```
 [ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-93 simple-client]$ mvn exec:exec
-Dexec.mainClass=”com.example.cassandra.App”
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (default-cli) on project simple-client: The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

However, sometime when i went into the `target/classes` and run `java com.example.cassandra.App`, it can show hello world! successfully. But when I add new java file like `SimpleClient.java` and compile it and run, it shows the error above.

Comment: The `exec:exec` goal is intended for external tools. What you should use is `exec:java` instead which is intended to start a Java app.

Comment: HI @khmarbaise, thank you so much for your reply. However, I've also tried exec:java command, but it still had the same error. And actually I'm running a java application. I've tried to target/classes and run java com.example.cassandra.App, it worked. However, when I add a new java file into the src and tried both methods, it failed. I'm not sure whether it's because the inappropriate setting of Maven or something else.